# Is there a way of telling a sink connector in Kafka Connect how to look for schema entries

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have successfully set up Kafka Connect in distributed mode locally with the Confluent BigQuery connector. The topics are being made available to me by another party; I am simply moving these topics into my Kafka Connect on my local machine, and then to the sink connector (and thus into BigQuery).

Because of the topics being created by someone else, the schema registry is also being managed by them. So in my config, I set `"schema.registry.url":https://url-to-schema-registry`, but we have multiple topics which all use the same schema entry, which is located at, let's say, https://url-to-schema-registry/subjects/generic-entry-value/versions/1.

What is happening, however, is that Connect is looking for the schema entry based on the topic name. So let's say my topic is `my-topic`. Connect is looking for the entry at this URL: https://url-to-schema-registry/subjects/my-topic-value/versions/1. But instead, I want to use the entry located at https://url-to-schema-registry/subjects/generic-entry-value/versions/1, and I want to do so for any and all topics.

How can I make this change? I have tried looking at this doc: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#configuration-details as well as this class: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/schema-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/subject/TopicRecordNameStrategy.java

but this looks to be a config parameter for the schema registry itself (which I have no control over), not the sink connector. Unless I'm not configuring something correctly.

Is there a way for me to configure my sink connector to look for a specified schema entry like `generic-entry-value/versions/...`, instead of the default format `topic-name-value/versions/...`?

Answer (score 0):

The strategy is configurable at the connector level.

e.g.

```
value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=...
```

There are only strategies built-in, however for Topic and/or RecordName lookups. You'll need to write your own class for static lookups from "generic-entry" if you otherwise cannot copy this "generic-entry-value" schema into new subjects

e.g

```
# get output of this to a file 
curl ... https://url-to-schema-registry/subjects/generic-entry-value/versions/1/schema 
# upload it again where "new-entry" is the name of the other topic 
curl -XPOST -d @schema.json https://url-to-schema-registry/subjects/new-entry-value/versions
```

Comment: Thanks, and do I just place the folder path to my class file in that parameter?

Comment: No. It must be a class name, as documented. I The class needs to be loaded either in the JVM classpath or in `plugin.path` as a JAR then restarting the Connect workers

Comment: So what I tried was creating a very simple class from this https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/schema-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/subject/TopicRecordNameStrategy.java and then making it into a jar file, placing that jar in my project, then adding it to the CLASSPATH (I'm using Docker, so the variable is just CLASSPATH: /etc/custom/build/TopicRecordNameStrategyCustom.jar). Then in the connector config file, I set "value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy": "TopicRecordNameStrategyCustom".

but it says class could not be found

Comment: Java is not my forte. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I've not personally tried creating a custom strategy, but you will need to use the full package name of the class, or if the Java class doesn't have a package definition, it needs to, in order to be imported by others